# autocomplete with tar and .xz

Tags: tar, autocomplete, xz

When I wish to unpack a certain file with `tar`, I type tar followed by my chosen parameters. Then I type the first(s) letter of the file name and then press the tab key, as to let the autocomplete feature to do its job. However, it does not work on my system with `.tar.xz`.

By default my system did not support `.xz` compression. However I added support to it manually, but I don't know what I shall modify to add support to it to the autocomplete.

My shell it is GNOME Terminal 2.30.2

So, what I have to do?

Comment: What is your system - in particular, which shell are you using?

Comment: GNOME Terminal 2.30.2

Comment: In general this is going to be very slow. In order to get a list of filenames in the tar.xz file the file is going to have to be decompressed. If you have enough memory or a fast enough disk it would make sense to decompress the tar.xz file once, and then do thefilename extraction and then the file extraction from it. A second issue is that filenames inside the tar file do not have to be unique.

Comment: Autocompletion is handled by your *shell*, not the graphical environment (Gnome, in your case).

Comment: Please execute `$SHELL --version` and add the resulting output to your question.